# Algorithm for people to congregate with limited relative location information

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

(If you have a good edit for the title, please comment so I can change it.)

I saw this problem a while ago and I can't seem to figure it out:

Some paratroopers jumped on an infinite plane and when they hit the ground, they were all dazed and passed out. After a while, the paratroopers begin to wake up at random times. They could all wake up very quickly or take a very long time. Eventually, they will all wake up, but for any time $t$ it's possible that a paratrooper will wake up after that time. Each paratrooper has a map that has the position of all the paratroopers. When a paratrooper wakes up, he activates the map to locate the other paratroopers, but it works only for a split second, so he can see the location of all other paratroopers but not the direction of their motion. It is pitch dark, so the paratroopers can't see anything around them. What is the strategy the paratroopers can adopt if they wish to congregate within $\varepsilon$ of each other, for an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$?

Clarification: The paratroopers can only see others relative to each other, they cannot tell direction (i.e., East-West, etc.).

Comment: I strongly suspect that the following strategy works: everyone heads for the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) of the set of locations they see.  For this to work, you need to show that if $S$ is a set with geometric median $m$, and some $s\in S$ is replaced by a point $s'$ on the segment connected $s$ to $m$, then the geometric median is unchanged. This is true for any $n$ points in one dimension, and for three points in $2$ dimensions. You also would have to deal with the fact that $m$ can only be computed approximately.

Comment: Thank you. I don't fully understand the geometric median and, apparently, there's no easy way to compute it. I tried to come up with a counterexample, but failed.

Comment: Actually, this does not work, even for two people! The problem is the median is not unique; any point on the line segment connecting the two people is a median. You could resolve this by saying that both people should head for the midpoint of their segment, but that does not work either: the first person could head for the midpoint, then the second person could wake up after and compute the wrong midpoint. Instead, with two people, the solution is to head for each other's points, guaranteeing they will collide.

Comment: I was overthinking it - I considered too many points and then couldn't find a counterexample. I had some ideas of trying to identify a special paratrooper. For example, consider the two paratroopers furthest apart. The rest of the paratroopers then move towards the line connecting those paratroopers. Draw the perpendicular bisector of the segment and the special paratrooper is the one with most paratroopers on his halfplane, so everyone should move towards him... but this doesn't work. For 2 troopers, they agree that one of them is special so the second trooper moves towards him.

Comment: We can solve the question for $n=2$ and $n=3$ people (for three people, they should head toward the Fermat point of the triangle, which happens to be the geometric median). I think it would be best to get a complete solution of the problem for $n=4$ before tackling the general case. For example, if the quadrilateral formed by the three people is convex, then a strategy which works is to head for the intersection of the diagonals (which will not change as people move). But what do you do if one person is in the triangle formed by the other three?

Comment: For $n=4$ you just head towards the person in the middle of the triangle - that person is the geometric median in that case, so I think that's fine. When it comes to 5 people, I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (though maybe not the intended one):

You can designate one guy as the meeting point. That guy does not move at all, and all others come to him. How do you designate the guy? simple: just choose the one who landed farthest to the east. Using the GPS should tell you wether you are the one or not.

Comment: Good solution, but we're talking about infinite plane here with no coordinates. I edited the question.

Comment: In the real world, GPS literally does coordinates ;) . Maybe what you mean is more like radar?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that two paratroopers can "see" each other once they are at same location. I think this assumption is necessary for the problem to be solvable for two paratroopers; the strategy in that case is they head to each other's location, stopping when they bump into the other.

The best I can do is two solutions which each work with some mild sounding additional assumptions.

---

Here is a solution which works if the pairwise distances between the landing locations are distinct.

> When you wake up, compute the distances between all pairs of paratroopers, and let A and B be the closest pair. If you are neither A nor B, do not move until they come to you.
>
> A and B will first find each other by heading to each other's location, meeting somewhere on the line segment connecting them. Once they bump into each other, they will repeatedly head towards the closest of the currently unfound paratroopers, and wait for them to wake up.
>
> If you are not A or B, then once A and B arrive at your location, you join the growing search party, heading towards the next closest unfound trooper.

---

Here is a solution which works as long as the paratroopers can make random decisions:

> When you wake up, memorize the $n$ current locations $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ of all the paratroopers, including yourself. Repeatedly choose one of the $n$ points randomly, head to the chosen point, and wait there for a random amount of time (namely, repeatedly flip a coin, and wait for one hour each time the coin is heads, stopping when you first get tails). If at the end of your waiting period, all other paratroopers are present, stop.

Since the paratroopers are moving around and wake up at different times, they will all compute different sets of locations $p_1,\dots,p_n$. However, they will all have at least one location in common. Namely, if $A$ is the last paratrooper to wake up (or even tied for last), then everyone's list will include the place where $A$ landed. Since at any point in time there is a positive probability  that everyone will head to location $A$ and wait there long enough for everyone else to arrive, the laws of probability guarantee it will eventually happen.

---

Comment: This works, but can we do this without the assumption that paratroopers can see each other (even if they are standing at the exact same location)? For 2 paratroopers, A and B, the two paratroopers can agree that once they land, they will head towards A's location. For 3 and 4 paratroopers moving towards geometric median works, just like you suggested.

Comment: @MishaShklyar The "head toward A" strategy sounds illegal, since it makes the problem trivial for any number of paratroopers. For 5 people named A,B,C,D and E, the winning strategy would also be to just head for paratrooper A! $\tag*{}$ I think we are not allowed to assume the paratroopers have preassigned names. Any labels like A or B need to be determined from the geometry.

Comment: @MishaShklyar BTW, can I ask where you heard this puzzle? I read it somewhere on the internet a long time ago, but I cannot find the source anymore. I am really curious about hunting down someone who knows what details about the rules are, and what the intended solution is.

Comment: I heard it from a friend a long time ago. For two paratroopers, they can agree which one of them is A and which is B before jumping. For 3 or more, this strategy doesn't work... Now that I think about it, if we allow paratroopers to communicate, we can just assign the "collector" before the jump who will go to the other paratroopers' locations and collect them, just like in your first solution.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, with three or more people the radar wont tell you who A is (but with two people, you know A is either you or the other guy). But yeah, it seems like a hidden requirement of the problem is that the paratroopers all have to use the same algorithm, but I am not so sure if the paratroopers should be allowed know when they bump into each other. This is all I can do without knowing the original source.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate all the time you put into this :)

Answer (score 0):

another approach:

Construct a [Minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of the positions. Then start from the leaves of the tree, picking up (and possibly waking up) people on the way. (So if you are not on a leaf-node, you are not allowed to move until you are picked up by people coming from the leaves.)

I dont think this is the intended way (probably @MikeEarnest has the "correct" solution), but I thought it was fun :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, your answers are fun and original :)

Comment: I am not convinced this works; what if some people moving causes the MST to change, and someone mistakes themselves for a leaf and starts moving too early? I am not sure this is wrong either, and it certainly seems promising, but it also seems hard to prove.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, this is not a physical problem. The paratroopers are really points and you can actually allow them to "pass" through each other. I.e., have multiple paratroopers at the same location. And they cannot "wake each other up" or "travel together".