# Sensitivity of geometric median to moving one point

Tags: geometry, statistics, convex-optimization

The *geometric median* of a finite set $S$ of points in the Euclidean plane is defined as the point $m$ for which $\sum_{s\in S} d(m,s)$ is minimized, where $d(x,y)$ is the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$. As long as $S$ is not colinear, the geometric median is unique.

My question is this; if you replace a point $s\in S$ with some $s'$ for which $d(s,s')<\epsilon$, will the geometric median of the new set be at most $\epsilon$ away from the geometric median of the original?

The reason I want to know is that I could use this result in order to solve the puzzle here: [Algorithm for people to congregate with limited relative location information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178943/algorithm-for-people-to-congregate-with-limited-relative-location-information).

I have verified this is true when $|S|=3$ and $|S|=4$, where the geometric median can be described explicitly. For example, when $S$ is the set of vertices of a convex quadrilateral, it can be shown the median of $S$ is the intersection of the diagonals. This intersection moves by less than $\epsilon$ when any vertex moves by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is it true that all near-minimizers of $\sum_{s \in S} d(\cdot,s)$ must be close to $m$? Here's why I ask. In your problem, let $m,m'$ be the medians for $S,S'$, respectively (where $S'$ is $S\cup\{s'\}\setminus\{s\}$). Then $\sum_{s \in S} d(s,m') \le 2|s-s'|+\sum_{s \in S} d(s,m)$. Does this imply $|m-m'| \le \frac{2|s-s'|}{n}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 It is not true in general that $|m-m'|\le 2|s-s'|/n$, because sometimes $|m-m'|=|s-s'|$. An example is then $S$ is four points, where $s\in S$ is in the interior of the triangle formed by the other three points. In that case, $m$ is equal to $s$, so moving $s$ moves $m$ the same amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. Let $S = \{(-2,0),(-1,1/4),(1,0),(2,0)\}$. Then $m = (1,0)$ (via mathematica, or by showing $(1,0)$ is a local minimum by analyzing small perturbations). Let $s = (1,0)$ and $s' = (1,1/4)$. Now, by symmetry and uniqueness of median, the new median, $m'$, has $x$-coordinate $0$. So $|m-m'| \ge 1$.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the median is only guaranteed well-defined when $S$ is non-colinear. For your colinear set $S'$, you can show that every point on the line segment connecting $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ is a median, as these points all minimize $\sum_{r\in S'} d(x,r)$. Therefore, _the_ median of $S$ is still within $|s-s'|$ of _one of the_ media of $S'$. I would therefore not qualify this as a counter-example.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh, I interpreted "colinear" as all points lie on a single line. Are you defining "colinear" as "there exist 3 points on a line"?

Comment: @MikeEarnest wait what? how is $S'$ colinear (under any definition)?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused, I agree your $S'$ is not colinear. I was confused since I thought I had verified this was impossible with 4 points, but clearly I was wrong. I will reward the bounty once I triple check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this statement must be true, and probably under looser conditions than you grant. Suppose we generalize to a unique median position $m_\alpha$ which minimizes the sum of the distances when the distances from $m_\alpha$ to all of the $s$ that are not moving are weighted by $\alpha$ in the sum. Then, $m_1 = m$. Moreover, $m_0$ is clearly just equal to the value of the moving $s$. That means that for $\alpha=0$ the distance this reweighted median travels is just the distance the moving point travels, $d(s,s')$. Because our result should be path independent, we choose the geodesic path from $s$ to $s'$.

Now suppose we calculate how fast $m_\alpha$ is changing as we increase $\alpha$. Intuitively, this extra function dilutes the effect of the one moving point $s$ so it can only decrease the distance the weighted median travels. This is true at every point in the trajectory of $s$ and for every $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ so the total distance the median travels keeps decreasing as $\alpha$ increases. Thus, we conclude that the total distance must be strictly less than $d(s,s')$.

For a more explicit demonstration of this "intuitive" property, consider a coordinate $x_\alpha$ that is the unique minimum of

$$f(x,\beta)+\alpha g(x)$$

so that

$$\partial_x f + \alpha \partial_x g = 0$$.

This above expression is evaluated at some $x_\alpha(\beta)$ so now let's differentiate both sides with respect to $\beta$, yielding:

$$(\partial_x^2 f +\alpha \partial_x^2 g) (\partial x/\partial \beta) + \partial_x \partial_\beta f = 0$$.

Here, then, the fact that $x_\alpha(\beta)$ is a unique minimum means that both terms in the initial parentheses must be positive. Hence, increasing $\alpha$ must decrease $\partial x/\partial \beta$ and we conclude that the total distance traveled, $\int d \beta (\partial x/\partial \beta)$ must also diminish at $\alpha$ increases.

Comment: This seems promising, but I have a doubt. In the last equation, you say that increasing $\alpha$ must decrease $\partial x/\partial \beta$, but couldn't it be the case that $\alpha$ increases, and $\partial^2_x f$ decrease to compensate? $\partial^2_x f$ does depend on $\alpha$, since $\partial^2_x f$ is being evaluated at $x_\alpha(\beta)$ in that equation, which depends on $\alpha$.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I confess, I'm relying more on the intuition than the calculation at this point. It just seems so impossible that strengthening other constraints would increase the median position's susceptibility to adjusting an existing constraint.